# Echarts from baidu with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts, echarts

I want to use Echarts from baidu in a web application. I want to draw a scatter graph using data from a csv file embedded in a web page form that I'm using asp.net as a backend framework. Is that possible?? If yes, is there any example that might make me understand better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. 
I am using that in same way but the backed framework is JSF. 
I have done below things....
 1. Download the echarts
 2. Copy the file echarts-2.2.7\doc\example\www2\js\echarts-all.js to project directory
 3. Load that in web page using script
 4. In another script tag need to write the required Options (look into the examples under the same directory)
 5. Just find the div id and pass as parameter to the echart init method
I guess this resolves your need... it done for me..